# Recycle Bin not Visible in Lightning

Tags: lightning, recycle-bin

I am not able to see **Recycle Bin** in my Sandbox.

Tried searching through **App Launcher** and **Tabs** still the Recycle Bin is not visible.

Please suggest a way to enable it in lightning. So, that it will be useful for all.

Comment: Have you checked the Tab permissions on the profile?

Comment: We had this situation in some of the orgs, but not the others. We raised a case with support and they enabled it for us.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is released in winter 20.

You have to follow the steps as mentioned in the release notes.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lex_recycle_bin.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=recycle_bin_manage.htm&type=5

And the other option is You can use pre-release org or wait for it to roll in the sandbox

It will answer your query.

Regards,
Abhishek Mudireddy.

Comment: Winter 20 release and your answer is not related to this issue. Thanks

Comment: Shyam Can you raise a case with the salesforce team so that we can check the backend and let you know what caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this issue is fixed by Salesforce Technical Support.

Created a Case in Salesforce.

**Tier 3 has enabled the permission from the backend** in our orgs,

1. Production.
2. PCSB.
3. Sandbox.